# Jcrop not working on bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, jcrop

I want to implement something like this, which is appear on [Bootstrap 3 modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

[image]

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/blob/master/demos/tutorial3.html), but not working, a radio button appear, and the `preview-pane` is missing

However, if put outside the modal, then it works.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Kashif [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jslim89/LqF39/) is the code

Comment: Have you found a solution?
I am stuck with the same problem. i think the problem is that the binding of jcrop_api to the original image isn't happening due to the modal. I have tried many things but havent been able to fix it

Comment: I change to [this library](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/). Like in mobile device, drag the image in the background, on top of that is a frame _(fix position)_ then only crop it

Answer (score 2):

as described [here](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/20) the input element is there to capture key inputs, you can turn this off by using keySupport: false.

Or you can add opacity:"0" to .jcrop-keymgr